# Get ListView content height

Tags: listview, react-native

How to get list-view **content** height(not list-view height). Is it possible to use the **onLayout** method for that?

Comment: Do you mean the child views of the list view? The parent won't track the childrens heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out. we can use the **onContentSizeChange** method to get list-view content height.

```
<ListView
    ref={ref => this.listView = ref}
    onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSize}
/>

onContentSize(contentWidth, contentHeight) {
    console.log("<<<<<< content >>>>>>>>>", contentWidth, contentHeight);
}
```